# What is the difference between channel types SVRCONN and SDR/RCVR ? How to decide when to use SVRCONN or SDR/RCVR pair?

Tags: ibm-mq

We have 2 appl. In which App2 sending & App1 is receiving msg. Below is the configuration.

```
App1 => Q Name : GIBTNBN.RCV.SYS1.TO.SYS2
        ChannelName: GIBTNBN.SVRCONN
        QMgr: M1
App2 => Q Name : IBLPWTW.SYS1.TO.SYS2.STATUS
        ChannelName: IBLPWTW.SVRCONN.TLS
        QMgr: M2
```

I know only about SDR/RCVR type of channels. But here I see at both appl's side type of Channel is Server Connection. As per IBM specs => "To send messages using a server channel, you must also create, on the other queue manager, a receiver channel with the same name as the server channel." I am wondering how despite of having different channel name and channel Type (as per spec it should be RCVR Type & with same name 'IBLPWTW') at receiver side , communication is still happening.

Please help me out to identify how SVRCONN channel type work.

Comment: Please also be careful to realize that a Server channel (SVR) that you also mention in your question is not the same as a server-connevtion channel (SVRCONN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- SDR/RCVR channels are used to allow for one direction communication between two queue managers.
- SVRCONN channels are used to allow applications to connect to a queue manager over the network, the application can both send and receive data over the SVRCONN channel. If the application happens to use CCDTs to specify the client end of the connection details these are called CLNTCONN channels and would pair with a SVRCONN channel. CCDTs are not required, applications can specify connection details programmatically or via JMS/XMS JNDI such as ".bindings" files.

In your setup you may have both types in use, if you don't see SDR/RCVR channels then perhaps the two queue managers communicate over a MQ cluster using CLUSSDR/CLUSRCVR channels.

Comment: Well, If i understood correctly from the replies , App1 is using MQI channel  GIBTNBN.SVRCONN to connect to  QMgr : M1 for both sending as well as receiving messages . But How M1 is communicating to M2 ? How M1 reads the correct messages incoming from Queue BLPWTW.SYS1.TO.SYS2.STATUS used by App2 ?   Which channel is linking M1 <-> M2 ?

Comment: @summary I can only say that it is not a SVRCONN. Only someone with access to the queue manager's configuration can tell you for sure how messages are moved between them.

Comment: I checked further the Q mgr M1 & M2 's configuration and found that both M1 and M2 are in clustered env. Each Q mgr has different types of channels associated with itself. There are channels of type SVRCONN, CLUSSDR and CLUSRCVR. If i have understood correctly it is like  channel of type  SVRCONN is used by App1 to connect to M1. While channels of type CLUSSDR/CLUSRCVR are used to connect  M1 to M2 .

Comment: That is correct.   A `CLUSSDR` is auto defined on M1 that is based on the `CLUSRCVR` defined on `M2`.